# Laravel $this->seed() from tearDownAfterClass

Tags: testing, laravel, laravel-4

PHPUnit supports the method `tearDownAfterClass`, which does something after each method in test class has been run. I would like te re-seed my application here. However, Laravel has this method as $this->seed(), so I need an instance of test class (I don't have one inside static method)

How do I call `$this->seed()` after each method in test class has been run?

Answer (score 0):

`App:make` can give access to DatabaseSeeder class:

```
public static function tearDownAfterClass(){
    App::make('DatabaseSeeder')->run();
}
```